# Can string lookups be vulnerable to timing attacks like array lookups are?

Tags: implementation, side-channel-attack, timing-attack

Per [“Can non-assembly crypto libraries truly be secure against timing attacks?”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27282/can-non-assembly-crypto-libraries-truly-be-secure-against-timing-attacks), array lookups are vulnerable to timing attacks. Like, if you do `cresult[map[i]]` and `map` is an array and `cresult`, is a string then `map` is vulnerable to timing attacks because it's an array but is `cresult`?

Comment: How would you expect strings to be stored in memory?

Comment: Since this can strongly depend on the chosen programming language, may I ask if you are simple asking “in general” or if you are refering to some specific programming language?

Comment: @yyyyyyy - I'm not sure but maybe contiguously? Although I gues string concatenation could make that not so easy..

Comment: If you consider C, then strings actually are arrays, so anything there can just be applied to both. But in general: It depends on the context and the actual usage in the algorithm. As a rule of thumb: If you have a algorithm where no one took explicitly care of sidechannels, it is very likely that there is one. This is especially true for any deterministic part.

Comment: A timing attack and a cache attack are different things.  A cache attack is not a concern if you don't have arbitrary processes executing on the same processor.  An array reference is typically time invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, string algorithms can be vulnerable to timing attacks.

A very common example is string comparison. The best performing way to implement it in general is to compare two strings one character (or memory word) at a time and return inequality as soon as they don't match. However, this kind of a routine is vulnerable to timing attacks that can find the (approximate) length of the common prefix. Using such a string comparison routine to compare passwords or hashes has lead to attacks ([an early 1970s example](http://www.meadhbh.org/services/passwords#TOC-The-TENEX-Password-Bug), [a random 2009 example](http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/)).

Similarly, when you are using a multibyte encoding, simply looking up a character in a string can allow timing to reveal details about the string before then.